# How do I add an authorization header to the HTTP request initiated by clicking a link?

Tags: hyperlink, http-headers, jwt, authorization, bearer-token

Suppose I want to add an authorization header with a bearer token (e.g., a JWT web token) to the request initiated by clicking a hyperlink so I can authenticate the user on the server before returning the requested content. How do I do that? I'm not using any web framework, just vanilla JS.